# How to prevent Windows 10 mobile hotspot from automatically turning off if not used

Tags: hotspot

Windows 10 mobile hotspot automatic turn off if not used.

It will automatic turn the hotspot hot after 5 or 10 minutes if I didn't use it.

How do I change this settings in mobile hotspot?

[image: Hotspot Mobile]

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to enable this?  It's quite unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had similar problem.  When I was not connected to my laptop's win10 mobile hotstop, it will turn itself off.

Tried to look for advanced settings for mobile hotspot but couldn't find, Other people suggested to turn off the power feature of the "network adapter" which in incorrect.

Instead of network adapter, you need to change settings of the hotspot virtual adapter.

---

Solution:

1. activate mobile hotspot.

2a. R click wifi system icon, then click network & internet settings.  you may need to click mobile hotspot option, then find the network and sharing center

OR

2b. control panel, network and sharing center.

3. you should see the mobile hotspot connection (check the hotspot ssid name), in addition to you internet wi-fi/ethernet connection.
4. click on the connection "ex: local area network" under your hotspot connection
5. click properties
6. you should see that "connect using" has microsoft wifi direct virtual adapter
7. configure
8. power management tab
9. uncheck - allow the computer to turn off this device to save power

Comment: this didnt work for me! Is there another solution?

Comment: In the 7th step configure is a "Configure..." button on the top of the properties window.

Answer (score 13):

I've created PowerShell script to turn on the Mobile Hotspot if it's not enabled yet. You Can save it as a .ps1 file and add it to the task scheduler (I've used [this guide](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler)).
Here is the script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
$asTaskGeneric = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' })[0]
Function Await($WinRtTask, $ResultType) {
    $asTask = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod($ResultType)
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtTask))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
    $netTask.Result
}
Function AwaitAction($WinRtAction) {
    $asTask = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and !$_.IsGenericMethod })[0]
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtAction))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
}

$connectionProfile = [Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation,Windows.Networking.Connectivity,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::GetInternetConnectionProfile()
$tetheringManager = [Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringManager,Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::CreateFromConnectionProfile($connectionProfile)
if ($tetheringManager.TetheringOperationalState -eq 1) 
{
    "Hotspot is already On!"
}
else{
    "Hotspot is off! Turning it on"
    Await ($tetheringManager.StartTetheringAsync()) ([Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringOperationResult])
}
```

Comment: Tested on Windows10, works.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a desktop application that continuously checks for the hotspot status and turns it on if it is off, the system tray icon shows hotspot status:

https://github.com/ashvin-bhuttoo/PersistentHotspot

Answer (score 2):

It's a little bit easier on  Windows 10 1909:
[image]

**Edit**: if that doesn't work, see kriegaex's comment & code below

Comment: This doesn't make any changes

Comment: Same results, it doesn't seem to make any change at all.

Comment: guys, you should send a bug report to Microsoft

Comment: Yeah, this used to work for 2 years on my machine, but since one of the latest Windows updates, it does not work anymore. Every night the WiFi reconnects, the hotspot is deactivated too. [This Powershell script](https://superuser.com/a/1472550/218289) activates it again, even on machines where `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` does not work due to the Wifi adapter's driver model - and it does not even need admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

The other PowerShell answer by DanceDance probably works, but I can provide a simpler PS script which accomplishes the same thing. That is, we want to enable the hotspot every one in a while programmatically so that if it's turned off because no clients are connected, it will be turned back on shortly.

Following a few other answers, here's my PS script:

```
$connectionProfile = [Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation,Windows.Networking.Connectivity,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::GetInternetConnectionProfile()
$tetheringManager = [Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringManager,Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::CreateFromConnectionProfile($connectionProfile)
while ($true) {
    $tetheringManager.StartTetheringAsync()
    Start-Sleep -s 300
}
```

This will enable the hotspot if it's off, checking every 5 minutes. By running this in PS, or through a regular command line by calling `PowerShell.exe -File script.ps1`, it will ensure that the hotspot will stay on for the majority of the time.

Comment: This gives me `Unexpected token 'GetInternetConnectionProfile' in expression or statement`. Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft think that it's not safe if you keep your wifi-hotspot on when there is no one connected to it.So Windows will turn it off after several minutes.Changing the power save configuration won't work for it.

Comment: The answer would be more helpful if you could post a reference.

Answer (score -1):

Go to microsoft Network Connections - Wifi Direct Virtual Adapter #2 Properties (it's your hotspot virtual adapter, might be a different name in your end) - Power Management - Uncheck turn off device. I haven't tested if it works.

Answer (score -4):

there is not such an option to disable that feature because microsoft did that so wireless hackers can't hack your hotspot if u don't use it for long time . and it will help your deivce to save some power maybe powersaving option should be disabled in windows mobile settings but if that didn't work there is some application like interop tools app that give you option to edit windows mobile registry but i can't search the registry of my phone to tell you is there anything about that in phone registry or not but u can do that if u have enough time . and the other way to achieve that is send an feedback about hotspot directly to microsoft and explane what you want and why maybe in next update they fix or add that option for you .im a windows mobile insider and in latest build i have an option to let other device that are already paired with bluetooth can turn your hotspot on . ( Trun on remotely - allow another device to turn on mobile hotspot. both devices must have bluetooth turned on and be paired. )

Comment: This is really hard to read. You should start using punctuation characters such as `,.` and making shorter sentences.