# Start mobile hotspot from the command prompt without Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot

I got tired of having to click on the network icon and the mobile hotspot button every time my computer starts or the mobile hotspot turns off automatically, so I wanted to automate the process using a batch file through the Task Scheduler.

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

However this command does not work for me and results in the following message:

```
The hosted network couldn't be started.
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.
```

I found on [Can't start hostednetwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182084/cant-start-hostednetwork) that I should enable the 'Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter' in Device Manager, but I have 'Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter' and 'Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2' instead.

I'm not sure if 'Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter' and 'Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter' are somehow related such that I can use a slightly different command from the command prompt to allow a batch file.

What can I do to turn on mobile hotspot via cmd?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Windows 10 mobile hotspot from automatically turning off if not used](https://superuser.com/questions/1148391/how-to-prevent-windows-10-mobile-hotspot-from-automatically-turning-off-if-not-u)